# gulp - uglify js files with browserify?

Tags: node.js, browserify, gulp-uglify

I am following the example from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vinyl-buffer) exactly and have my own version:

```
gulp.task('build-js', function() {
    var bundler = browserify('js/*.js');

    return bundler.pipe()
        .pipe(source('bundle.min.js'))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
        .pipe(livereload());
});
```

But why do I get this error:

```
$ gulp
[21:48:33] Using gulpfile /var/www/html/mysite/gulpfile.js
[21:48:33] Starting 'apply-prod-environment'...
Setting NODE_ENV to 'production'
Successfully set NODE_ENV to production
[21:48:33] Finished 'apply-prod-environment' after 169 μs
[21:48:33] Starting 'build-js'...
[21:48:33] 'build-js' errored after 11 ms
[21:48:33] TypeError: bundler.pipe is not a function
```

What have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that example provided by `vinyl-buffer` has a mistake:  You must call `bundle()` before adding transforms, not `pipe()`:

```
return bundler.bundle()
    .pipe(source('bundle.min.js'))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
    .pipe(livereload());
```

Another example is provided in the [Gulp](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/de1acf66a6253302c856971f8c00f65ea6c63882/docs/recipes/browserify-transforms.md) repository (one should indeed use the browserify API directly in Gulp).

Comment: i just noticed that too!

Comment: I'll take care of suggesting an edit to the readme file. :)
https://github.com/hughsk/vinyl-buffer/pull/6